# jquery hasClass without breaking chain

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a jquery selector which finds: all `data-toggle=collapse` which dont have a class of `no-hide`

I try which doesn't select anything.

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]:has(.no-hide)').click(function(){
```

Error:  $(...).hasClass(...).click is not a function

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').hasClass("no-hide").click(function(){
```

Only works if there is 1 class name.

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse][class=no-hide]').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `not` method:

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').not(".no-hide").click(function(){
```

**Update**: If you want to select the elements that have `no-hide` class, you can use `filter` method:

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').filter(".no-hide").click(function(){
```

Comment: I want the opposite of `not`, its more like AND has class

Answer (score 2):

try [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').not(".no-hide").click(function(){ 
   //your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `~` in selector. It will work even if there is more than one class.

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse][class~=no-hide]').click(function() {});
```